# Directory to upload the cron file cron.txt

Tags: php, cron

i have a file named `cron.txt` which has the following script

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://www.divinotech.com/send_data
```

i am using the url to call the file,

now

i just want to know, where to upload this file and how to invoke this...

the problem is that i am totaly new to this, and i dont have any idea regarding this

Comment: your question is not clear. you want to install a cronjob? is it on a dedicated server? Or shared hosting, wich control panel do you use ? d

Answer (score 0):

To use the crontab you have to copy this text to `crontab`.

Steps:

- type `crontab -e` (`e` stands for `edit`)
- paste the line `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://www.divinotech.com/send_data`
- save and exit (normally it will be vi editor, so you'll have to type `:wq` - w for save, q for quit)
- check if everything has been writen properly by writing `crontab -l` (`l` stands for `list`). It will show the actual information saved in crontab.

From that moment, your script should execute every 5 minutes. Anyway, if it does not come back to this site and ask, as there would be some issues to check.

Good luck!